# Asp.Net Net 5 Force browser to read certificate from smartcard

Tags: c#, blazor, identityserver4, asp.net5

I need to upgrade an activex smartcard authentication in IE to a Blazor web authentication in Net 5. It is mandatory an Authentication via SmartCard with PIN. I setup identityServer4 as for [Configure certificate authentication in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/certauth?view=aspnetcore-5.0) but when login page  is called, the smartcard reader doesn't read the smartcard inserted in the client. I need to validate the login on the server against the certificate to be read in the smartcard on the client.
There is a way to accomplish this goal? Or somehow through a blazor client-side page? thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to read the smartcard info from a controller in identity server, you would use:

```
var cert = Request.HttpContext.Connection.ClientCertificate;
```

I'm fighting the same struggle.  I was able to make IdentityServer4 do smartcard authentication, but it wouldn't pass a token back.  I modified it to use a different method of authentication but I get the info off of the smartcard.  It's somewhat working for me.  I wish there was a better way.

Comment: Thanks Joe. The problem is that ClientCertificate is always null. Anyway the customer required to abandon identity server and I was forced to  manage a way to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

The customer required to abandon identity server and I was forced to manage a way to solve the problem.
I created a WebApi and i configured it to require a certificate as for https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/certauth?view=aspnetcore-5.0 .
Any method you expose in the WebApi require the certificate and you can get it through
`X509Certificate2 clientCertificate = await HttpContext.Connection.GetClientCertificateAsync();`
and process it according your needs i.e. returning the thumbprint.
On the server you need to install the certificate authority relating to your smart card in the trusted certificate root in order to webapi works, otherwise you get a "Forbidden" response (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/sdn/articles/installing-the-trusted-root-certificate).
On Blazor **client** side you just call the webapi endpoint and smart card is read and you type the right security code to get the response you need